# How can I get the first section of a page 100% width, while the rest will have a sidebar?

Tags: widgets, sidebar

I'd like to have on all my pages - except the index/blog page - a usual widget sidebar. But on the very top I will need 100% of the width for a table. The header with the page title is already at 100% by the theme, but the main content is around 80%, due to the sidebar. Is there a chance to get the first paragraph/a specific ID etc. at 100% and everything below just like it is with the sidebar?

All custom widget plugins and grid creator plugins I found so far are either not capable of doing this or require heavy overload (for example with Visual Composer you can't put a widget placeholder in the sidebar. So you'd need to change the sidebar on every single page. The same goes for Elementor or OTW Grid Manager).

Comment: Which theme are you using (since it depends on that). Some themes have it 'out-of-the-box', while you can tweak others to achieve it... But I can also imagine some themes which can't be setup in those ways. :-/

Comment: I am using the free theme [Appointment](https://de.wordpress.org/themes/appointment/). It does not have it out-of-the-box. But is there no way to restructure the HTML/DOM structure? The first section just needs to be above the actual content section. But I am not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: And if you're interested in getting that 'Put on hold'-thingy off the question (for some reason), then I'd rephrase the question, where you include information about the Appointment-theme and maybe a screenshot or something. I think your question is valid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... Yeeeeh, - I guess it could be done. But I'm unsure how difficult it is.

But I have a baaaaaaad feeling about this theme, though. I've just installed it. And I may be blind, but I can see no installation-instructions or documentation of any kind (only a `readme.txt` with aged/outdated links, like this one: http://www.appointpress.com/theme/appointment ). And the theme-files are quite a mess... For instance, which of these files should you edit in order to edit the homepage-template:

- `home.php`
- `index-home-callout.php`
- `template-homepage.php`

However, - if I open `home.php`, then I can see this:

```
<?php
if ( 'page' == get_option( 'show_on_front' ) ) {
    get_template_part( 'index' );
} else {
    get_header();

    //****** get index static banner  ********
    get_template_part( 'index', 'slider' );

    //****** Orange Sidebar Area ********
    get_sidebar( 'orange' );

    //****** get index service  ********                
    get_template_part( 'index', 'service' );

    //****** get Home call out
    get_template_part( 'index', 'home-callout' );

    //****** get index News  ********
    get_template_part( 'index', 'news' );

    get_footer();
}
?>
```

So `get_sidebar( 'orange' );` tells me that there is some kind of support for a sidebar. Plus, it's positioned under the slider, so it looks like that someone actually have already made what you're after.

... Maybe you'll get access to it, once you upgrade to the pro-version.

I can find all kind of different information on how reponsive, cool and hot this theme is, but no instructions or FAQ or anything.

Plus... If you hard-code it in the code, then if the developer updates the theme (and you update it in your WordPress-installation), then you'll (possibly) overwrite your customizations (and have to do it again).

So I guess I would say, that in order to achieve what you're attempting, then I'd either:

1. Write your question to this oh-so-amazing support, that the theme-website is bragging so much about ( source: https://webriti.com/appointment/ ) .

or

2. Purchase the 'Pro'-version of the theme and pray to Helen of Troy, that the documentation/further instructions will come along with that.

But every cell in my body is screaming the well-known words of Gandalf: **Run, you fool!** :-)

... Find a better theme, mate. My experience is that it's a good investment to want to pay a dollar or five on a theme; since you'll then get a theme with a developer who (hopefully) spend time developing it and documenting it well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I went for a few paid themes in the past but never was too positively surprised. That's why I wanted to try this good looking one. Do you know any free theme that might be able to do what I am looking for or do you think this can only be done by "PRO" versions?

Comment: Sorry mate, but I've been let down by pre-made themes so many times; that I've decided to put that whole chapter behind me. I've never heard of a pre-made theme that 'just really hit the spot'. There's very often something annoying about it, in some way or another. But I'm fairly sure that 'Appointment' isn't amongst one of the good themes. But I would google for 'Best WordPress Themes' and find a comparison-site like this one: https://www.codeinwp.com/blog/best-free-wordpress-themes/ . And it would be a 'must' that there was good instructions/documentation for it.

Comment: If this answered your question, then remember to mark it as an answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll go for your recommendations. I just hope I can find something to make it look like [here](https://seo-marketing.tools/seo-tool-test/xovi/) for example. But let's see how it turns out. I will mark this as solved.